# Linked list queue number move

Tags: c++, oop, linked-list, queue

I have an input linked list queue [2,5,3,1,2,4].
How can i move all even numbers to beginning and odd number to end in an output file?
I can't change the order of the numbers for instance it cant be [2,4,2,1,3,5].
It have to be [2,2,4,5,3,1].
I have already implement the queue, but i dont know how to do the sort.

Comment: You can not sort a queue.

Comment: At least not without taking everything out of the queue and sorting it as you put it back in again

Comment: I recommend using another queue.  Pop the values from the master queue to the temp queue until a value is not sorted.  Insert back into the master queue, in sorted order.  Repeat until the master queue is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another queue. So you start with two queues:

```
q1: [2,5,3,1,2,4]
q2: []
```

You know the length of `q1`.

Now, remove an item from the head of `q1`. If it's even, add it to `q2`. If it's odd, re-add it to `q1`. Do that for every item in `q1`. It looks like this:

```
step 1:
q1: [5,3,1,2,4]
q2: [2]

step 2:
q1: [3,1,2,4,5]
q2: [2]

step 3:
q1: [1,2,4,5,3]
q2: [2]

step 4:
q1: [2,4,5,3,1]
q2: [2]

step 5:
q1: [4,5,3,1]
q2: [2,2]

step 6:
q1: [5,3,1]
q2: [2,2,4]
```

Now that you have them split into even and odd, you remove things from `q1` and add them to `q2`.